# What are the alternatives of Zest in visualizing diagram?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef, data-modeling, zest

I have a need to create a diagram viewer. There is hierarchical tree that I want to visualize in Eclipse plugin. I manage to know GEF, and there is Zest. But in Zest, I don't success in creating custom shape in graphic nodes and there is no tutorial to create the custom node (I have been searching all day). So I want to know if there are alternatives beside Zest. What I like most from Zest is it provides layouting algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to edit that tree? If not, I would use the Zest framework.

[This](http://git.eclipse.org/c/gef/org.eclipse.zest.git/plain/org.eclipse.zest.examples/src/org/eclipse/zest/examples/swt/GraphSnippet4.java) might help you to create the custom shape.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) which is popular and has an [eclipse plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsegraphviz/). Note that I have never used it.

Comment: Zest can visualize dinamic diagram, and I think GraphViz doen't have that capability

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your LabelProvider implement the IFigureProvider interface, and override the getFigure method to return a custom IFigure implementation which draws your custom shape and has its colors set the way you want them.

However, there seems to be a bug in support for highlighting support for a custom node. The bug report gives a patch, and claims it has been fixed, but I don't see the fix appearing in current (4.3) version of the Eclipse plugins. I don't know why. (Does anybody else?) I made a copy of the plugin and patched it manually. Here is the bug:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=335136